# Install lubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: software-installation

I have just installed lubuntu 13.10. I am trying to install lubuntu-restricted-extras, so I can download/enable adobe flash player or alike? (so I can view video content on youtube, etc)

I read the following:

> When you installed Lubuntu, you had a chance to check a box enabling you to install restricted addons that enabled things like MP3/DVD/Flash playback. If you forgot to do this, you can still install these packages by opening the Lubuntu Software Center (version 12.04 and later) in the menu under System Tools. Search for “lubuntu-restricted-extras” and, when the selection loads, click “Install.”

(I have tried this method but I am unable to find lubuntu-restricted-extras when searching in the Lubuntu Software Center (typed this in the top right search box?)

I have also tried to enter this manually by entering - sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras in Synaptic Package Manager......but I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly!

I have also read the following - I installed the extras and all is fine now. There is actually lubuntu-restricted-extras now.

Please could someone example easy to follow steps the correct procedure if installing a plug-in or adobe flash player (1st time using a linux os)

Comment: Don't edit your question to ask additional questions. If ypur original question has been answered, mark the solution as correct and ask a new question. One question per post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are doing it the right way but the package exist:

```
apt-cache search restricted-extras
kubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Kubuntu
kubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Kubuntu
lubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Lubuntu
lubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Lubuntu
ubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
ubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Ubuntu
xubuntu-restricted-addons - Commonly used restricted packages for Xubuntu
xubuntu-restricted-extras - Commonly used restricted packages for Xubuntu
```

You can open the terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras` type your password and done.

Comment: Hi, please could you explain what i have to do step-by-step. 1st time i've ever used a linux based os,,thxs

Comment: Read the last paragraph.